# sorting higher and lower values in a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I got a vector that contains 4 elements who are not sorted, the vector looks like this :

```
vector<positionInfo> objects
```

where positionInfo is a struct :

```
struct positionInfo
{
  int X_pos;
  int Y_pos;
}
```

now, these 4 elements are not sorted, but I want them to be in a specific order, which is :

- Element 1 ( [0] ) must have the lowest Y and X pos.
- Element 2 ( [1] ) must have the highest X pos but the lowest Y pos.
- Element 3 ( [2] ) must have the highest Y and X pos.
- Element 4 ( [3] ) must have the lowest X pos but the highest Y pos.

this is just to easily access any of the 4 points who form a cube, using a lot of variables can probably get me what I want but that's not really optimal I think, are there any algorithms I can use to decrease the size of the code and increase the speed?

Comment: your question is a bit ambiguous - what does lowest Y and X pos really mean?  (eg if I have (1,10) and (7,2), what is the answer to the lowest Y and X pos question?)  Can an answer be a point that is not in your vector, `objects`?

Comment: no, only working with the 4 elements, they decide what the lowest X and Y pos are, which are obviously where the Y_pos and X_pos in the struct have the lowest value of all of the 4.

Comment: so what if my four inputs are (1,10), (7,2), (12,0), (10,1), what do you expect your four answers to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you completely sure that you have a solution, you can partly use `std::sort`.

For example (3 steps):

Overload `<` operator:

```
bool
operator < (const positionInfo & left, const positionInfo & right)
{
    return left.X + left.Y < right.X + right.Y;
}
```

Next, sort your vector:

```
std::sort( &objects[0], &objects[4] );
```

Notice, that in this example vector has precisely 4 elements.

As a result, you will get a vector, where first and last elements are sorted according to your wish.

Last step - swap interal elements if it needs:

```
if ( objects[1].X < objects[2].X )
    std::swap( &objects[1], &objects[2] );
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are not *local* to the data. You should have an information about all the elements to calculate, if one element is bigger or smaller, than another.

I'l illustrate this with the image:

[image]

Considering only (1) and (2) or (3) and (4) it's impossible to say, what should be bigger:

If (1) and (2) had their *y* coordinates greater then (3) and (4), they would swap their positions.

Usual search algorithms, however, work only in assumption, that you can compare elements *locally*, so you could decide, which of two elements is greater, considering only 2 elements.

*So you cannot use standard sort algorithms*.

Instead, you should make new vector and fill it with elements according to the conditions:

```
new_objects[0] = find_elememt_with_lowet_x_and_y(objects);
new_objects[1] = find_element_with_highets_x_and_lowest_y(objects); 
//....
objects = new_objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- Four points do not form a cube - it has 8 vertices. IF you meant determine a cube probably you need 3 dimensions. I am assuming you speak of square
- In case you actually are not dealing with squares, but with random 4 points your sorting is not clear - `Element 1 ( [0] ) must have the lowest Y and X pos` for example it is not required to have the lowest `y` and `x` in the same point.

If, however, you meant square, not cube and are really sure you want to deal with this situation you can do it the following way

- Cycle all four vertices
- find the minimal and maximal `x` and `y`s
- because you are sure of the situation you deal with you can create the 4 points of interest out of those 4 values.